# Tangent spaces via derivations.

Tags: differential-geometry

I am a little stumped by the definition of the tanget space via derivations.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space#Definition_via_derivations

Is it reasonable to think of these as "directional derivatives in the direction of a tanget to a curve" even in the general manifold setting? In $\mathbb{R}^n$ the directional derivaitve pops out rather direct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A brief answer: yes this is essentially the same as the case for $\Bbb R^n$. The idea is to use a local coordinate system $(U,x^i)$ on $M$ to induce an isomorphism of tangent spaces $T_pM \cong T_{\phi(p)}\Bbb R^n$ via the differential $d\phi_p\colon T_pM\cong T_{\phi(p)}\Bbb R^n$ and then define our "directional derivatives" as $\partial/\partial x^i|_p \equiv (d\phi_p)^{-1}(\partial/\partial x^i|_{\phi(p)})$. (Confer with almost any book that treats smooth manifold theory in some detail, say Lee or Bröcker and Janich.)

Comment: The trick it that we kind of move this identification that we make in $\mathbb{R}^n$ between directional derivatives and tanget vectors, back to the manifold. Thats whats tricky about it. The pullback of the differential that one could call a tanget to a cruve in the manifold isnt really a tanget but a function on functions defined near the point.